# How to ask maven to create maven-metadata.xml and not maven-metadata-local.xml?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3, maven-metadata

For some reasons (not the concern of this post) amazon S3 is not a perfect host for maven repository. so i am building my maven application in a local machine and at some points in time (like every two days or so) i copy the whole hierarchy to amazon S3 with `aws s3 cp` command. say i copy the com folder which is like :

```
com
-raysis
--rayProduct
---1.0-SNAPSHOT
----rayray.jar
```

the problem is the metadata file that has been created is **maven-metadata-local.xml** (since i have built it locally it seems reasonable) but when i upload it to S3 and trying to get it with maven, it complains that there is no **maven-metadata.xml**. so how can i force (or ask gracefully) maven to create maven-metadata.xml instead/along-side of maven-metadata-local.xml?
since there is no location specific data inside  maven metadata, it seems not to be problem prone move.

Note:
i am trying to load the dependency from S3 with following dependency( i have added the repository too):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.raysis</groupId>
    <artifactId>sense-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have no experience on what you're doing, but have you tried anything with [resources:copy-resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html)?

Comment: @watery The Resources plugin is probably not going to help here. Artifacts are not resources.

Comment: Why don't you use `mvn deploy` to deploy your artifacts to an external repository?

Comment: @GeroldBroser hmmm.. it is a bit tricky with aws s3. but i will look into it